# Copy folder with sub directory in Docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to copy a folder with contents. But when trying to access the file from docker it shows an error

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements/development.txt'
```

My Dockerfile contains:

```bash
FROM python
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apt-get update \
    && pip install pip install gunicorn
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements/* /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install -r requirements/development.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers", "3", "cryb.wsgi:application"]
```

Comment: Please do NOT post images of error messages. Please copy and paste the text instead. Text is more accessible to everybody (be it screen readers, the google bot or people why simply want to google part of the error message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
COPY requirements/* /usr/src/app/
```

You're copying stuff from requirements to /usr/src/app. This does NOT preserve directory structure. Make that

```
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/requirements
COPY requirements/* /usr/src/app/requirements/
```